# Django (13) Permission denied: AH00035: access to / denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path on Mac OSX

Tags: django, macos, apache, permissions

I am trying to deploy **django** project in **apache** on Mac OSX.

Follow all steps from [Deploy Django on Mac OSX](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/05/02/build-and-deploy-a-django-project-on-osx-from-scratch)

**Getting this error in log:**

```
(13)Permission denied: [client ::1:63146] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Set `include /private/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/localhost.conf` in **/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

Create a file - **localhost.conf** inside **/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost

    # Static files
    DocumentRoot "/Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/"
    ErrorLog "/Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/error.log"
    CustomLog "/Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/access.log" common
    Alias /static/ /Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/static

    <Directory /Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/static>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess test python-path=/Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test:/Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/virtual_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup test
    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment/test/myproject/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
```

How can overcome the issue of **Permission** ? Even I set the permission to **django-project( test )**

Comment: Try `ls -al /Users/nitinsolanki/Documents/virtual_environment`

Comment: @Wtower: Tried then what ?

Comment: Check to see if the web server has file permissions.